# Google Webmaster Tools: hreflang not recognised

Tags: international, seo

I have on all the pages of my website hreflang tags pointing to the alternate versions containing translated text. But in the Google Webmaster Tools I still see this message:

[image]

Any clue? I've added the hreflang tags about a week ago now. http://lorenzoraffio.com/?lang=en

Comment: Please *do not* use URL shorteners here. They are unnecessary and are too often used to disguise spam or other undesirable links.

Comment: Search engines are notoriously slow. As well, the Search Console (webmaster tools) can be slow on it's own. You may need to give it more time. Cheers!!

Comment: Your hreflang tags point to your HTTPS site.   Which version of your site did you register in Google Webmaster Tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've said, you do have the tags in place. However, there are two discrepancies in the setup:

1. Your site currently allows itself to be served [over HTTP](http://lorenzoraffio.com/index.php?lang=en) and [over HTTPS](https://lorenzoraffio.com/index.php?lang=en). Your hreflang tags are set up for HTTPS only. I imagine that is intentional, so you should set up a 301 redirect to force all requests over HTTPS.
2. Your home page has a duplicate: https://lorenzoraffio.com/?lang=en, and https://lorenzoraffio.com/index.php?lang=en. In your question, you linked to the first one of those, and on that page all the hreflang tags point to the `index.php?lang=xx` versions. Again, you'll need to edit your application code or server-side redirects, so that requests to https://lorenzoraffio.com/ are redirected to https://lorenzoraffio.com/index.php

Beyond that, I'm afraid you just have to wait for Google to crawl your site and find the tags. But these two issues I've mentioned do stand in the way of a proper hreflang implementation, so it is worth fixing them now.